# Why is String#delete not deleting the `-` char from this string

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to sanitise some phone number data by using the `#delete` method, but according to my testing in irb it is only deleting the '-' character when i present it in a certain order in the argument.

`"(941)979- 2000".delete(" -().")` still returns with the - present; => `"941979-2000"`
whereas
`"(941)979- 2000".delete(" ()-.")` does remove the -; => `"9419792000"`

What is it that I am misunderstanding about this method's argument requirements?

Comment: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-delete

Comment: I would like to make a few suggestions for organizing questions you submit to SO. Here you start by saying, "I am trying to sanitise...", but readers will not understand what you mean by that so those words are just a waste of ink. You need to be specific about what you are trying to do without any reference to the code you tried. After stating the problem in words, give one or more examples for illustration if you think that would helpful to readers. Important:  show the desired result for each example you give. With that finished you can then describe what you tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation of `String#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/String.html#method-i-delete), the [*Character Selector*](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.1/character_selectors_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Character+Selectors)  `-().` means:

- ANY character between   and `(` (which is  , `!`, `"`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, and `(`) OR
- `)` OR
- `.`

I.e. the set of all characters selected by this *Character Selector* is  , `!`, `"`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, and `.`.

Whereas the *Character Selector*  `()-.` means:

- OR
- `(` OR
- ANY character between `)` and `.` (which is `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `-`, and `.`)

I.e. the set of all characters selected by this *Character Selector* is  ,  `(`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `-`, and `.`

In other words, the first *Character Selector* does not select the `-` character because the `-` is not present in the set of selected characters whereas the second *Character Selector* does select the `-` character because the `-` is present in the set of selected characters.

Without knowing your precise requirements, my guess is that the *Character Selector* you actually want is something like  `\-().` or  `()\-.` or simply  `().-`.

Comment: Ahhhhaaaa, I completely see now @Jörg, the dash character that I was using was being interpreted as 'between the left char and right char in the character range', silly me . I should have thought to escape it. Thanks so much for the very clear and well written answer.

Comment: It appears that escaping the hyphen has no effect: I get the same result with `" \-()."` as with `" -()."` Shouldn't the hyphen be placed at the beginning or end of the string if it is to be considered as one of the characters to be deleted?